# Why do jQuery .prev() and .next() work incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why when I use .prev() (the same goes with .next()) here to launch all audios except the one before r2, it starts all except r2 and some random one (not exact previous)? It should play only the previous to the r2 element. I try to understand this

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="RadioN.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#i1").click(function(){
var player = $("audio").not("#r2").prev();for(i=0; i<player.length; i++) player[i].play();
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#">
<img id="i1" src="r1.png" style="height:50px"></a><br>
<div>
<audio class="r" id="r1" src="https://rs103-krk-cyfronet.rmfstream.pl/RMF24" controls preload="none" style="visibility: visible"></audio>
<audio class="r" id="r2" src="https://radiostream.pl/tuba10-1.mp3" controls preload="none" style="visibility: visible"></audio>
<audio class="r" id="r4" src="https://c13.radioboss.fm:18296/stream" controls preload="none" style="visibility: visible"></audio>
<audio class="r" id="r5" src="http://stream.affordablestreaming.com:8000/KDDL.mp3" controls preload="none" style="visibility: visible"></audio>
<audio class="r" id="r6" src="https://p10.p4groupaudio.com/P10_MM" controls preload="none" style="visibility: visible"></audio>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$("audio").not("#r2").prev()` will select the elements with the IDs of r2, r4, and r5. So what is it that you're really trying to do?

Comment: I try to select all IDs except the one before "#r2" and make them .play. In this case it the answer is "choose all except "r1"", but I try to understand the general way of using .prev() and .next(). 

The idea behind this is to learn how to code "play audios of all except 3 previous and 3 next IDs of a given ID"

Comment: `.not("#r2").prev()` isn't a contextual process. `.not('#r2')` has no bearing on how `.prev()` functions.

Comment: .not accepts a function, that you can use identically to .filter to filter any elements that precede #r2 directly out from the collection. Alternatively, .not also accepts a collection, so you could select #r2's previous sibling and pass it to .not. `.not($('#r2').prev())`

Comment: You're right. fmquaglia has also corrected my misunderstanding. But now how to code "play all except the one before r2"?
And finally "play all except the previous ID of a given ID, the second previous and the third previous of this given ID"?

Comment: Would you suggest something like
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#i1").click(function(){
var player = $("audio").not($('#r2').prev()); for(i=0; i<player.length; i++) player[i].play()
});
});?

Wow, it actually works!

Comment: I have also tried this:
$("audio").not($('#r5').prev()).not($('#r5').prev().prev());
And it successfully stops both the previous and the second previous one! Thank you very much!

Comment: @PaulW you asked one thing while trying to do totally something else. Just out of curiosity, what are you building?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `prev` method will return the array of previous siblings of the elements matching `.not('#r2')`.

`.not('#r2')` will return `[audio#r1.r, audio#r4.r, audio#r5.r, audio#r6.r]`.

`.not('#r2').prev()` will return `[audio#r2.r, audio#r4.r, audio#r5.r]`.
This is :

- `#r1` previous sibling will return none
- `#r4` previous sibling will be `#r2`
- `#r5` previous sibling will be `#r4`
- `#r6` previous sibling will be `#r5`

If what you want is to play only the previous sibling to `#r2` you should use a more deterministic selector. something like `$("audio#r2").prev().get(0).play()` may be?

Comment: thank you for this clarification! I clearly misunderstood the relation between .not and .prev.
Actually what I intend to do is to play all except the previous sibling to #r2